# Is there a platform solving allocating N students with preferences to project topics?

Tags: r, project, allocation

Student have 3 ordered choices for project topics.

The topics are linked to supervisors. The supervisors have varying numbers of topics each. In addition, each supervisor also has constraints about how many students they will supervise in total.

If there are several students per topic, we have a ranked list who should get priority.

We've been doing this manually for years, but with increasing student numbers, it's less and less fun...

It's a bit more complex than one would think at first sight, because of the workload constraints, so it can't be coded up that quickly. So, I am wondering if anyone has already done that and it's sitting somewhere on GitHub or Moodle repos. I would be looking for R code, as I don't know Python or Julia (yet). Or, more conveniently, maybe there is some kind of app that could be used for it, like doodle pools etc.?

Comment: Hi Julia! This seems like an interesting problem. Would you be able to mock up some data that will help folks troubleshoot? And even better - example data and the desired outcome of those data. That will likely get you much faster, more targeted responses and improve the quality of answers. Otherwise folks are just guessing. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Happy to help out the educational world. Let me know if I can describe this better or if it encourages you to edit your question with more information.

#### Creating fake & reproducible data

```
set.seed(1234) # used for repeatable random data in this example
# First we create the fake topics data.frame
topics <- data.frame(topic = LETTERS[1:6], 
                     supervisor = c("John","Richard","Harriet","Brianna","Merlin","Lawrence"),
                     student_limit = c(5,2,4,2,3,5),
                     students_assigned = 0)
topics
#      topic supervisor student_limit students_assigned
#1     A       John             5                 0
#2     B    Richard             2                 0
#3     C    Harriet             4                 0
#4     D    Brianna             2                 0
#5     E     Merlin             3                 0
#6     F   Lawrence             5                 0

sum(topics$student_limit) # for this example we'll have some spare spots
#[1] 21

# create fake students with fake preferences
n <- 20
student_names <- sample(rownames(USArrests), n, replace = F)
student_preferences <- cbind.data.frame(student_names, t(replicate(n, sample(topics$topic, 3)))) # fake top 3 sample
colnames(student_preferences) <- c("student","choice1","choice2","choice3")
student_preferences$topic_assigned <- NA
student_preferences$choice_rank <- NA
student_preferences
#              student choice1 choice2 choice3 topic_assigned choice_rank
#1          Nevada       F       D       E             NA          NA
#2          Kansas       E       D       F             NA          NA
#3        Michigan       C       D       F             NA          NA
#4          Oregon       E       B       A             NA          NA
#5            Utah       B       C       D             NA          NA
#6         Florida       D       C       E             NA          NA
#7      California       A       C       B             NA          NA
#8    Pennsylvania       D       B       C             NA          NA
#9       Wisconsin       B       E       C             NA          NA
#10       Arkansas       F       A       B             NA          NA
#11   North Dakota       C       A       E             NA          NA
#12   Rhode Island       A       F       D             NA          NA
#13  West Virginia       B       A       C             NA          NA
#14        Montana       C       B       D             NA          NA
#15       Colorado       F       C       A             NA          NA
#16           Iowa       C       A       B             NA          NA
#17        Indiana       F       E       A             NA          NA
#18 South Carolina       C       F       B             NA          NA
#19     New Jersey       E       B       C             NA          NA
#20    Mississippi       F       D       E             NA          NA
```

#### The allocation process

This algorithm will fill up based on who gives their preferences first.
If the student's first preference is filled, it moves to their second, and then their third

```
for(i in 1:n){
  # CHOICE 1
  topic_row <- which(topics[,"topic"] == student_preferences[i, "choice1"])
  if(topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] < topics[topic_row, "student_limit"]){
    student_preferences[i, "topic_assigned"] <- student_preferences[i, "choice1"]
    student_preferences[i, "choice_rank"] <- "choice1"
    topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] <- topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] + 1
    
  } else {
    # CHOICE 2
    topic_row <- which(topics[,"topic"] == student_preferences[i, "choice2"])
    if(topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] < topics[topic_row, "student_limit"]){
      student_preferences[i, "topic_assigned"] <- student_preferences[i, "choice2"]
      student_preferences[i, "choice_rank"] <- "choice2"
      topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] <- topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] + 1
      
    } else {
      # CHOICE 3
      topic_row <- which(topics[,"topic"] == student_preferences[i, "choice3"])
      if(topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] < topics[topic_row, "student_limit"]){
        student_preferences[i, "topic_assigned"] <- student_preferences[i, "choice3"]
        student_preferences[i, "choice_rank"] <- "choice3"
        topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] <- topics[topic_row, "students_assigned"] + 1
        
      } else {
        student_preferences$topic_assigned[i] <- "could not assign"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### End Result

```
student_preferences
#          student choice1 choice2 choice3   topic_assigned choice_rank
#1          Nevada       F       D       E                F     choice1
#2          Kansas       E       D       F                E     choice1
#3        Michigan       C       D       F                C     choice1
#4          Oregon       E       B       A                E     choice1
#5            Utah       B       C       D                B     choice1
#6         Florida       D       C       E                D     choice1
#7      California       A       C       B                A     choice1
#8    Pennsylvania       D       B       C                D     choice1
#9       Wisconsin       B       E       C                B     choice1
#10       Arkansas       F       A       B                F     choice1
#11   North Dakota       C       A       E                C     choice1
#12   Rhode Island       A       F       D                A     choice1
#13  West Virginia       B       A       C                A     choice2
#14        Montana       C       B       D                C     choice1
#15       Colorado       F       C       A                F     choice1
#16           Iowa       C       A       B                C     choice1
#17        Indiana       F       E       A                F     choice1
#18 South Carolina       C       F       B                F     choice2
#19     New Jersey       E       B       C                E     choice1
#20    Mississippi       F       D       E could not assign        <NA>
 
topics
#  topic supervisor student_limit students_assigned
#1     A       John             5                 3
#2     B    Richard             2                 2
#3     C    Harriet             4                 4
#4     D    Brianna             2                 2
#5     E     Merlin             3                 3
#6     F   Lawrence             5                 5
```

So you will still have cases where the top 3 weren't met. Would need to know what you'd like to occur in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will have a play at this. Unfortunately, they closed this question as apparently asking for code/software/tools/apps aren't supposed to go on Stackoverflow (which I hadn't realised). In my experience, the biggest problem is the supervisor's availability. As to your questions, I would consider asking students for more than 3 choices in the future. In the meantime, we may have to be creative and solve it on a case by case basis, such as convincing some supervisors to take two students working on the same topic (varying it a bit). Many thanks again!

Comment: Yeah if you had just said your problem and that you were trying to solve it in a particular language and showed what you did so far/put a reproducible example dataset, pretty sure they would have left it open. Good luck!